# Are there parallel universes in any mythology?

Tags: myth-identification

There are some sci-fi themes that can be sometimes scratched from some mythological tales like time travel in Mahabharata or Irish mythology.

Is there any mention of parallel universes (multiverse) in any of mythology or ancient legend?

Not some hidden worlds but more like planes where there is a version of your reality were everything could have been different depending on some choice.